# How do I use Joomla and Ajax detect screen size to adapt my navigation?

Tags: php, ajax, mobile, joomla

I want to create a mobile website site, I'm trying to get my navigation to adapt to screen size. The HTML structure of the navigation is going to change, I'm aware that I can use CSS and @MEDIA calls. However, it doesn't apply in my case, because I'm using a [Foundation from ZURB](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/) framework, I need to change the elements, from UL to DD or DL, etc.

I looked around on several sources and I find that because PHP loads first before my AJAX is ready, I can't get my navigation to display properly on mobile devices.

I needed some way to detect my screen size and communicate that value to my PHP menu generating function in Joomla.

I tried the following:

```
window.onload = function(){ 
var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '',
    data: {
        "height": height,
        "width": width
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
});
}
```

mod_menu sample:

```
<?php
   require_once('FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
   $firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);
   ob_start();

   $width = $_POST['width'];

   $firephp->group('Test Group');
   $firephp->log('Width');
   $firephp->log($width);
   $firephp->groupEnd();
?>

if ($width > 767) { 

?>

<!-- The class on the root UL tag was changed to match the Foundation nav style -->
<ul class="nav-bar<?php echo $params->get('class_sfx');?>"<?php
    $tag = '';
    if ($params->get('tag_id')!=NULL) {
        $tag = $params->get('tag_id').'';
        echo ' id="'.$tag.'"';
    }
?>>
<?php
foreach ($list as $i => &$item) :
    $id = '';
    if($item->id == $active_id)
    {
        $id = ' id="current"';
    }
    $class = '';
    if(in_array($item->id, $path))
    {
        $class .= 'current ';
    }
    if($item->deeper) {
        $class .= 'parent ';
    }

    $class = ' class="'.$class.'item'.$item->id.'"';

    echo '<li'.$id.$class.'>';

    // Render the menu item.
    switch ($item->type) :
        case 'separator':
        case 'url':
        case 'component':
            require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_'.$item->type);
            break;

        default:
            require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_url');
            break;
    endswitch;

    // The next item is deeper.
    if ($item->deeper) {
        echo '<ul>';
    }
    // The next item is shallower.
    elseif ($item->shallower) {
        echo '</li>';
        echo str_repeat('</ul></li>', $item->level_diff);
    }
    // The next item is on the same level.
    else {
        echo '</li>';
    }
endforeach;
?></ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Then I use a if condition to check the width of the screen and choose the type of navigation. One navigation uses a UL structure, the other one has to use DL DD struture.

I used FirePHP to see how the page loads, my navigation doesn't show up because the PHP loads first before the Ajax is ready, so I don't see my navigation. I need  my PHP to wait till the Ajax is ready or a portion of the page to wait. I'm not sure where to go from here.

I'm looking at Joomla MooTools, not sure if I can leverage that to wait for the Ajax to load before the page loads.

I'm aware, there are easier ways, like making a brand new menu item in Joomla or hiding things in Joomla to get it to work, but I want a more clean and elegant way.

If anyone has any code samples. Please post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to identify by browser:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16
```

I found a good guide [here](http://www.mlynn.org/2010/06/mobile-device-detection-and-redirection-with-php/).

Answer (score 0):

See below url

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=642&t=718062

OR Read it

I think you might be making this much harder then it has to be. Normally I would suggest using CSS and @media, which can still be implemented to allow any adaptive styling to be loaded using existing standards without the need to write any new code. The adapting of the module image sizes is where the meat of your "issue" is however; and this will require some hand rolled goodness.

Did you write the slideshow module code? You could easily run a quick script to get the screen size, and then alter the image size parameters passed from db params field to your code, to reflect the desired size depending on the screen.

If you didn't write the slideshow code or don't want to hack it, my suggestion would be to create a Joomla Content Plugin, where each time Joomla renders a new page, your plugin will check for two things, are any slideshow modules loaded and the size of the screen. This way also has the added benefit of allowing you to incorporate any new module or component specific layout/design changes needed for your adaptive design without having to re-invent the wheel.

Let me know how this goes, this is actually identical to a project I was just handed for our companies Joomla portfolio and will be working on this problem as well.

Comment: I've already seen this, I'm not looking to use CSS and @Media to solve my navigation issue, because Foundation already uses Media styles for my Navigation and overall styles throughout the website.

Comment: I wonder if I use headers, would that get me the screen size?